# "mycreatedwpsite.example.com is currently unable to handle this request. 500."

Tags: wordpress, server, localhost

[image]

I have developed a site on WordPress.org locally on my computer.

And I wanted to launch the site online.

SO.

I purchased a GoDaddy Domain. I purchased Bluehost hosting.

And wanted to transfer the site from local server to hosting service.

I found a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cM9Z8aQTCvQ At 2:27 the tutor shows, "Before we export the database we need to change our URL.".

I did it. And I hit the "save changes" button. After that I have been trying solution after solution all over the internet.

Bluehost's ftp manager. Filezilla file transfer. Bluehost's WordPress installation (I imported my theme, didn't work.) 
Tried different videos of move WordPress from localhost to server.

I found lots of articles about this problem on Internet. Even Codex WordPress Changing Site URL article.

But nothing from suggested solutions works for me.

And nothing works.

My local site by WAMP server and WordPress.org still looks amazing.

And after typing domain URL web browser still shows "isn't working."

**Edit**

PHP logs show:

> [24-Mar-2016 16:10:50] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   array_replace_recursive() in
>   /home2/hotelpo5/public_html/wp-content/themes/ta-pluton/inc/post-types/CPT.php
>   on line 512

Comment: A 500 error is usually a PHP error.  Can you see your host's PHP logs?  If so, can you post any errors here?  And can you clarify - the site no longer works on your local machine?  Or it's only failing on the Bluehost server?

Comment: ^_^ Thank You for trying to help me. ^_^ It is sooo nice of You. If there could be more people like You ^_^

On my WAMP server PHP error logs I found the last entry like this: 

"[23-Mar-2016 00:08:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: When I opened the file php_ldap.dll, I got shocked. Sooo many numbers. 
The first 5 lines are 


"4d5a 9000 0300 0000 0400 0000 ffff 0000
b800 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1801 0000
0e1f ba0e 00b4 09cd 21b8 014c cd21 5468"


(Maybe it rings a bell for You, but for me it makes no sense. Note to myself - need to study deeper this field - like obsessed.)

Comment: Finding the error log on Bluehost's server. 
Opening File Manager public_html folder.
When access the error log file in Bluehost's File Manager public_html folder, the all of the entries are the same - like this --

Comment: "[24-Mar-2016 16:10:50] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  array_replace_recursive() in /home2/hotelpo5/public_html/wp-content/themes/ta-pluton/inc/post-types/CPT.php on line 512"

Comment: Opening the file CPT.php.
The line 512 is the part of  (function register_taxonomy) (which starts on line 431. ).

The line 512 in CPT.php file looks like this (and also the following lines):

Comment: "
// Merge default options with user submitted options.
  $options = array_replace_recursive( $defaults, $options );

  // Add the taxonomy to the object array, this is used to add columns and filters to admin panel.
  $this->taxonomies[] = $taxonomy_name;

  // Create array used when registering taxonomies.
  $this->taxonomy_settings[ $taxonomy_name ] = $options;

 }
"

Comment: [Gosh, I am learning so many new things with Your help :D ]

P.S. Answering the question about the working website. 
The website is working properly on local machine. When I type "localhost" in the web browser, the website is as I would expected - as I developed. 
And the failure is when I type the domain name of my website. 
The outcome after domain name typing is my previous posted photo - that the site is unable to handle this request. 


P.P.S. I hope I got little more insight in this problem. Maybe You can help me more. Waiting for Your awesome mind to come up with some ideas ^_^

Comment: Since it's working on local, don't worry about WAMP. The `array_replace_recursive()` error is the problem. One possible problem is Bluehost running an old version of PHP, but according to [this page](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/php-version), Bluehost offers PHP 5.4 and 5.6, so we can probably rule that out (though please confirm your version as outlined on that page).  [This page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get_header-on-new-installation) suggests deleting all the files you've uploaded (except `wp-config.php`) and re-uploading.

Answer (score 0):

One reason that causes this issue is suppressed fatal error. Try enabling `error_reporting` and `display_errors`.

If you need to test the settings without modifying `php.ini` you can use something as below.

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score -1):

For the future googlers.. for me this was a permission issue which got messed up after I had checked a tag out using `Git`. So all I had to do was run the following command inside the **website root** to reset the permissions back to `Directories:755` & `Files:644`.

```
chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w ./
```

Further more the checkout had also messed up the file ownership. So I ran the following command inside the **website root** to set it back to the specific `user:usergroup`.

```
chown -R web1:client0 ./
```

**Note:-** Your `username:usergroup` would vary, so you shall have to adjust the above command to fit your environment.